# Trigonometric identity with sin, cos, and tan

Tags: trigonometry

Very cool problem I was reading today!

$(1)$ $2\sin^2 A $ – $ 2\tan A \sin A + 2 $ – $ \sin^2 A $ – $ \cos^2 B = 0; $

$(2)$ $2\cos^2 B $ – $ 2\tan A \cos B + 2 $ – $ \sin^2 A $ - $ \cos^2 B = 0;$

If $\sin A ≠ \cos B$, find the value of **$\boxed{\sin^2 A}$**

$\\$

I realized there was an easy simplification in equation $(1)$; $2 \sin^2{A} - \sin^2{A} = \sin^2{A}$

There was another easy simplification in equation $(2); 2\cos^2{B} - \cos^2{B} = \cos^2{B}$

After simplifying $(1)$ and $(2)$, I got

$(3)$ $\sin^2 A $ – $ 2\tan A \sin A + 2 $ $ – \cos^2 B = 0$;

And $(4)$ $\cos^2 B $ – $ 2\tan A \cos B + 2 $ – $ \sin^2 A = 0$

Adding $(3)$ and $(4)$ gives

$(5)$  $- 2\tan A \sin A + 2\tan A \cos B + 4 = 0$ which can also be written as $\tan{A}(\sin{A} - \cos{B}) = 2$

Subtracting $(3)$ and $(4)$ gives

$(6)$ $2\sin^2{A} - 2\cos^2{B} - 2\tan{A}(\sin A - \cos{B}) = 0$

Substituting $(5)$ into $(6)$ gives

$(7)$ $2\sin^2{A} - 2\cos^2{B} - 4 = 0$

I am not really sure what to do after this. Could someone please explain what I should do? The $\sin{A}$ and $\cos{B}$ are very different and I can't seem to use any identities to solve the equation.

Comment: Equation (6) seems interesting. Since $\sin A- \cos B\neq 0$ you can divide by $\sin A-\cos B$...?

Comment: That's a cool idea but then we're stuck with $\sin{A} + \cos{B}$ which we can't do anything with

Comment: Your $(7)$ does not have a solution, it's maximum is $-2$. Something is amiss with the problem, are you sure it's stated correctly?

Comment: @Vasya I think I did state the problem correctly, if the original problem was correct itself.

Comment: @Iamaperson: I think I found your mistake, please check my answer :)

Comment: @Vasya thank you! That was my error!

Comment: When examining the answer of @Vasya, who dissected your work, as mathSE protocol required, notice that there is a shortcut.  You could have avoided at least part of  your original analysis, and instead **immediately** concluded that $$\tan A(\sin a + \cos B) = 2$$ just by adding together the original equations (1) and (2), **as is** (without modification), in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a sign error in (5), it should be $-2\tan A \cos B$. 
Thus, $$ \tan A(\sin A+ \cos B)=2$$ and $$\sin^2 A-\cos^2 B=\tan A (\sin A - \cos B) \implies \sin A+ \cos B=\tan A$$ Can you finish now?

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question and I see the mistake I made!

Comment: Just a quick question, how would you use cos B to figure out sinA^2?

Comment: @Iamaperson: you don't need it, we get that $\tan^2 A=2$ or $\sin^2 A=2(1-\sin^2 A)$

Comment: Ohhh thank you so much!